# EntityFramework: unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'system.data.sqlclient.sqlclientfactory'

Tags: entity-framework, azure

I have an Website that use Entity Framework and SQLServer.
WHen I trying to run my application on Azure I get the following error:

```
Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'system.data.sqlclient.sqlclientfactory'. make sure that the ado.net provider is installed or registered in the application config.
```

On premises everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have finally discovered that the error was caused by this configuration section (that now I don't use anymore):

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, mysql.data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

I have removed it and now it worked correctly.

Comment: I am facing similar problem. Can you please let me know when I can find below section? <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, mysql.data" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

Comment: @Urvashi You should find it inside the web.config file of your web site.

Comment: I checked my web.config file but it does not exist

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, this same error can also be seen when using Visual Studio 2017 v.15.7. I spent days browsing the web for solutions, and stubled upon this [GitHub post](https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox/issues/710) mentioning a bug in EF Tooling. An update to v.15.8 as mentioned in the post solved the problem for me.