# Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type > 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Attempting to run integration tests in a project using Entity Framework 6 resulted in the error:

> SetUp : System.NotSupportedException : Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET
>   provider is installed or registered in the application config.

But the tests on same project works absolutely fine on several of my colleagues' machines and I have no local changes.

Have attempted reinstalling EF, [I don't have any unnecessary config sections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907079/entityframework-unable-to-determine-the-provider-name-for-provider-factory-of-t) or [Glimpse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903037/entity-framework-profiler-asp-net-mvc4-with-ef-6-unable-to-determine-the-prov) and [I've tried targeting a different version of the framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327811/unable-to-determine-the-provider-name-for-provider-factory-of-type-system-data) but the error persists...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out I have an empty, duplicate `DbProviderFactories` element in both my Framework/Framework64 **machine.config** files, which appears to have been created by the installation of the IBM DB2 .NET provider (?!). The duplicate node is rendering the **machine.config** invalid, so the issue is localised to my machine.

Modifying

```
<DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="IBM DB2 for i5/OS .NET Provider" invariant="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for i5/OS" type="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Factory, IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cdb2ebfb1f93a26"/>
    <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/><add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
</DbProviderFactories>
<DbProviderFactories/>
```

to remove the extra node:

```
<DbProviderFactories>
    <add name="IBM DB2 for i5/OS .NET Provider" invariant="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for i5/OS" type="IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Factory, IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cdb2ebfb1f93a26"/>
    <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/><add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/>
</DbProviderFactories>
```

Resolved the issue.

Comment: That was my case! I did not even know that DB2 was installed on the machine and finding here that a malformed machine.config could be the case, I also found the DB2 entries there. Thank you.

I was using DotNet 4.5.2 which it is irrelevant.